# Adding Swagger to application

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I am looking to add swagger to our application and making the changes on our backend codebase.
I have installed the nuget package Swashbuck.AspNetCore.

In the Startup.cs file I have made the following changes:

In the ConfigureServices method I have added

```
        services.AddSwaggerGen();
```

and in the Configure method I have added:

```
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();
```

Now from what I've looked at, it seems that should enough to then be able to redirect to the swagger page on the application. However, when I try to go to http://localhost:4200/swagger
I'm just redirected to http://localhost:4200. So I am wondering what I am missing here? Is there something else I need to add to the backend? Or is it possible there is something in the frontend that's causing the redirect away from it?

Comment: Try following the [getting started](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#getting-started)

Comment: are you sure your port number is correct. to access swagger you need to provide the port on which your webapi is listening.

Comment: yeah you were right, I was trying to access it from the wrong port number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So face palm moment. I had been trying to access from the wrong port number, I for some reason assumed it would be the same port that the front end uses but it is not. There are some other issues with loading the swagger UI but I can at least get to the page now